# AJAX Update Separate Element

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm developing a voting system using PHP and when I click on the "Vote Up" or "Vote Down" links for a particular item, I'd like the "vote.php" script to be run and the "Votes" value to be updated to reflect it's new value without the page refreshing. I'll need to be making a POST request via Ajax and I'd prefer to be able to do this using jQuery.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can easily be achieved by use of `.ajax` and the `success` parameter from the `.ajax` function within jquery

its all here:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

So, example:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/test.html',
  success: function(data) {
    $('.result').html(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: Great, once I'm writing code in the "success" parameter how can I get a specific DOM element to "refresh" so it shows it's updated value?

Comment: i updated the post to reflect the answer to your question. notice the targeting of .result

Comment: Thanks, but I still do not grasp the concept entirely. Where is the "data" variable coming from? Is that data that's returned from the url?